# (Node.js) application that lets me edit a local file through a web browser?

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, node.js

I wonder if there is a Node.js application that starts a server on the current folder to let me edit files through the web browser?

Kinda like http://www.cloud9ide.com, but for general editing (scripts, text etc).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Mozilla Skywriter](https://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/) - they are in the process of converting their server code to node.js.

Comment: I have never understood Bespin/Skywriter. Is it a ready-to-use web editor or is it like a library/framework allowing programmers to make a ready-to-use web editor like Cloud9?

Comment: It is usable in its embedded form as a 'drop in' inside web pages...but they also have a server component. It allows for plugins on both the server and client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can now try making your little node.js app online with http://jsapp.us/.

It's a sandbox with Bespin/Skywriter editor and the commands to save and deploy a node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

Its outside the scope of your question but if you have php access you could use http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ and just set the value of the input field to the file you want to edit.

Then when you submit just have it overwrite the file you opened.  I know its not using javascript like you asked but I though I would offer the suggestion its how I do what you where looking for.